# Trying to change the style of a webpage using a css class in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, themes

So I'm trying to make a webpage that, when a button is clicked, a certain "theme" rather than just single color is applied to the webpage. So I created css classes that contains different webpage styles.

However, I cannot seem "apply" the theme to the webpage, I'm really a beginner  so anything you think may be useful will be greatly appreciated.

Also I don't want to do this by using any automated webpage design since I need to understand how it works.

Comment: Could you add some code demonstrating what you've already tried?

Comment: Make sure you've saved the file, restarted the server, cleared cache, etc. If none of that works, you might get better responses in Server Fault, since that's all about server administration -- however, you'll wanna read their [Help Center](http://serverfault.com/help) before posting any questions.

Comment: I'm just not sure where to start, I have a list in HTML `<ul>

            <li onclick="changeTheme()" class="midnight">Midnight</li>


            <li onclick="changeTheme()" class="matrix">Matrix</li>


            <li onclick="changeTheme()" class="peardrop">Peardrop</li>



            <li onclick="changeTheme()" class="skylight">Skylight</li>

            <li onclick="changeTheme()" class="sunset">Sunset</li>

        </ul>`
But I'm not sure how to make the webpage change to the css themes I have chosen when they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically switch up a theme, you can use css [Descendant](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/) selectors. By changing a class on a parent container you can switch the theme up in a relatively easy manner. Check out the snippet below for a very basic and ugly example.

The css has the two theme classes named `theme` and `theme-2`. By putting `.theme h1 {mystyle}` any `<h1>` tag that is a descendant of an element with the `theme` class will have `mystyle` applied to it.

The Javascript is using jquery to add a click event listener to the `#button` selector (the link with id `button`). When the button is clicked, `$("#parent").removeClass("theme").addClass("theme-2");` removes the class `theme` from the element with `id="parent"` and applies `theme-2` to the same element.

```js
//javascript (using jquery)
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#parent").removeClass("theme").addClass("theme-2");
});
```

```css
/*css*/

.theme h1 {
  color: green;
}
.theme p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.theme h4 {
  text-align: right;
}
.theme-2 h1 {
  color: red;
}
.theme-2 p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.theme-2 h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="theme">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div>
    <p>This is some sample text</p>
  </div>
  <h4>This is a h4</h4>
  <a href="#" id="button">Click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to understand your code, I have tried to interpret it into my code but I'm not sure I understand fully what it's doing. If I have this right, when elements with the div id "button" are clicked, it removes the class "theme" from all elements that have id "parent" and replaces it with class "theme-2" ?

What if I wanted it to do different things for different elements of an unorganised list?

Comment: do you mean something like a list of themes to select from?

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.